# Three column layout with two floats left and right and one fixed width center

Tags: html, css

What I want is that I have images that should reside on the outside of the screen when it's big enough to fit the full page. In the center I have a container which has the width of 1200px and when I resize the background images on the left and on the right should not overlap with the center div.

I got that working but what I cannot get done is the direction to where the background image should overflow, the left image should overflow to the left and not the right when resizing and the right image should overflow invisible to the right. I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytgaajsd/2/) here that shows the problem.

I have a parent, a left side that should contain the left image and a right side that should contain the right image. The divider has the same size as the space it should not overlap with.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
</div>
```

This is what I want but when I resize and the image doesn't fit the width the div anymore I want the behavior that I would get when I position the left image to the right and the right image to the left.

Expected result on larger screens:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e40hzngum938axs/Screenshot%202014-11-10%2011.47.31.png

Expected result on smaller screens:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fdvdyqkxew9ozl/Screenshot%202014-11-10%2011.50.43.png

I have tried several things, with floats, img tags, overflow properties but I cannot seem to find a solution that works. Can I solve this with css alone or should I switch the background position from left to right and vice versa?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ytgaajsd/5/ Isn't this what you are looking for? For the left image to be fixed to the right, and start disappearing from the left, and the right image to be fixed to the left, and start disappearing from the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries to change the background position based on screen width. In the following example, assume that the images are 560px wide and the center column is 100px wide:

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.parent { display: table; width: 100%; min-width: 300px; }
.parent div { display: table-cell; height: 700px; }
.divider { width: 100px; }
.side:first-child { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry434.png") red no-repeat top left; }
.side:last-child { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIVja.png") red no-repeat top right; }
@media screen and (max-width: 1219px) {
  /* screen is narrower than 560 + 100 + 560 means there is not enough room for the image */
  .side:first-child { background-position: top right; }
  .side:last-child { background-position: top left; }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="side"></div>
</div>
```

The other solution is to always center align the image. In this case you need to make sure that the image is wide enough to cover large screen sizes and the *important bits* are at the horizontal center of the image. You will also need to set a minimum width so that sufficient portion of the image is fully visible:

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
 /* 2 x 300px min. image width + 100px fixed content width = 700px */
.parent { display: table; width: 100%; min-width: 700px; }
.parent div { display: table-cell; height: 700px; }
.divider { width: 100px; }
.side:first-child { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry434.png") red no-repeat top center; }
.side:last-child { background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIVja.png") red no-repeat top center; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="side"></div>
</div>
```

- [Left Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry434.png)
- [Right Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIVja.png)

Comment: The overflowing is now correct but I actually want the images to show on the outside of the browser when the screen is big enough, now the left image is shown at the right side of his parent while I want it to show on the left side when there is room enough.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e40hzngum938axs/Screenshot%202014-11-10%2011.47.31.png?dl=0) is what I am trying to make work, bird images on left and right should stay on outside of screen when it's big enough. [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fdvdyqkxew9ozl/Screenshot%202014-11-10%2011.50.43.png?dl=0) should happen when it's resized or viewed on smaller resolutions. So the left side of the birds on the left side should overflow and right side of birds on the right should dissapear and should not overlap the center.

Comment: I don't know any elegant solution. A hackish solution is to use a wide image where the birds are in the center of the image. Then align both images `top center`.

Comment: Good idea, hadn't thought of that, the only solution I thought of was to switch background position when the parent div width is smaller than the image width with javascript, but that's hackish as well.